# Would SysAdmin/Network Admins know what sites I'm connecting to through my VPN?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, vpn, proxy

I'm currently Connected to our Company Internet through WiFi using HTTP proxy. I was going over some wiki site. Probably its about gaming information.

This Page opened.

```
Access Denied (content_filter_denied) 

Your request was denied because of its content categorization: "Informational;Games"

For assistance, contact your IT Administrator.
```

Then I tried using my phone with VPN app like Psiphon. I got connected to whatever site I needed.

Question is ..

1. Would they be able to track me?
2. What sites I opened?
3. Browsing Behavior?
4. Is there a better VPN app? *out of superuser context*

Comment: They might notice there's encrypted traffic going out, walk over to your desk, and shouldersurf

Comment: I think answer for 1 to 3 is as wide as it is debatable but 4 ? **The answer is No, VPN apps are built to help you connect to a different network not break the security policies**. I also wonder they don't use mobile device management solution.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek how would they know its me and walk over to my desk?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like they do have. Normally the mobile phones cant connect to the Access Point by password only. I have to configure my port and proxy hostname to get it work.

Comment: @Hexxed They would know you by various things, like authentication tokens used by you and hardware asset(MAC ID, hostname) used by you can be tied back to you too

Comment: The corporate security policy is there for a reason. Guess what, they want you to work and not spend your time browsing gaming sites. If you have a website required for work that is blocked you can open a ticket asking them to unblock that website. That's how it works. PS: Yes, we can see what you're doing exactly and trace you back through various means.